# Open the localhost website from a server pc

Tags: server, ip, localhost, html

This might be an easy question, but I am not familiar with these stuff.
Basically I have a server pc that I connect through my pc, and there is this webpage http://localhost:8080/. I can only access this address when I log in my server pc. Now I wanted to know how I can access this webpage in my pc (without having to remotely connect to my server pc). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you get the IP address of the server? `localhost` only refers to the current machine you are using

Comment: Yes, that one I can get.

Answer (score 1):

you can access to your website (if your web server accept external requests) by type this code to your browser address bar from your pc:

```
<server ip>:8080
```

replace

```
<server ip>
```

with your server ip like this:

```
192.168.1.10:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so quick networking 101, `localhost` is a hostname that maps to the IP address of of `127.0.0.1` and these point to the local machine, i.e. your server.

In order to access that page within the same network, you'll need an external IP address. So say you're in the network of `192.168.1.0/24` and the server is on IP address `192.168.1.100`. So in order to access your stuff from another machine, simply replace `localhost` with that IP  and it should work. If not, you've got firewall issues, and those are another topic.

Comment: thanks, I now have an idea. It still didn't open, so I am assuming there is some firewall issue :) and as you said, that's another topic

Comment: @falco - Or the server is only running locally. Can you update your question with what you are using to run the server so you can get a complete answer? Apache? Node.js? Other?

Comment: actually it does not have an internet connection (it doesnt open any webpage other than this localhost:8080), and I am using the program 'Remote Desktop Connection' to connect with it. So, it's basically another desktop pc that is only accessed via remote connection.

Comment: @falco - I didn't say anything about Internet. There is a difference between a wide area network (WAN) (aka, the internet) and a local area network (LAN) (aka, your personal network). Obviously the server is connected to a router if you can remote desktop to it, therefore it has an external IP address. You still have not provided what you are running on the server at port 8080 or how

Comment: sorry, I may have misunderstood. As I said, I am not familiar with these stuff :)) I don't know about apache or node.js, I don't think its any of these. Basically, there is a Jenkins server configured there: [link](https://jenkins-ci.org/) that is used for running some tests, and at localhost:8080 is the main screen where the results of the jenkins tests are being shown.

Comment: @falco - What do you type into the remote desktop box to connect to your server? The machine name, like `MY_SERVER`? If so, trying entering `http://MY_SERVER:8080` in the web browser.

Comment: that works at the server pc, but unfortunately not at my pc :/